# NSCFNumber isEqualToString: crash IOS11 between viewDidLoad and viewWillApear

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

I have a crash only on IOS 11 :
**[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance**

Debug step by step indicates that the crash occurs **after the end of viewDidLoad and before enter viewWillApear**

**How can I debug?**

I tried with an exception breakpoint but I have no more informations. 
the crash is clear but I don't have any code and before of after the moment of the crash I don't use "isEqualToString" or "objectAtIndex"...

ViewDidLoad code :

```
   self.buttonCancel  = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"ANNULER" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(actionCancel)];
[self.buttonCancel setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [EATColor colorBlack],  NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[EATFont ElleNovaCExtraBold:12],NSFontAttributeName,NSKernAttributeName, @(0.66), nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[super viewDidLoad];

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

[self buildCollectionViewListing];

self.collectionView.delegate = self;
self.collectionView.dataSource = self;
self.collectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitle:@"ANNULER"];


[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"EATSearchRecetteCollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"idSearchRecette"];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"EATSearchArticleCollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"idSearchNews"];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"EATSearchGalleryCollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"idSearchGallery"];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"EATSearchVideoCollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"idSearchVideo"];
[self.collectionView registerNib:[UINib  nibWithNibName:@"EATSearchHeaderCollectionViewCell" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]] forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:EATSearchHeaderCollectionViewIdentifier];

if (self.searchedText) {

    if (self.searchBar) {
        self.searchBar.text = self.searchedText;
    }else {
        self.title = [self.searchedText uppercaseString];
    }

    [self loadData];
}
```

Comment: What's the full crash log? It doesn't happen on iOS10?

Comment: Is your ViewController has a super class ? Did you check super viewdidload ? what object do you add into your viewController ?

Comment: When it crashes, type "bt" in the debug console at the "(lldb)" prompt. Add that stack trace to your question.

Comment: The full crash log : Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c022ffc0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185447d38

Comment: can you show `viewDidLoad` code so we can check it

Comment: bt in the debug console : 
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGABRT
    frame #0: 0x0000000184f61348 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__pthread_kill + 8
    frame #1: 0x0000000185075354 libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 396
    frame #2: 0x0000000184ed0fd8 libsystem_c.dylib`abort + 140
    frame #3: 0x0000000184934068 libc++abi.dylib`abort_message + 132
    frame #4: 0x0000000184934210

Comment: libc++abi.dylib`default_terminate_handler() + 304
    frame #5: 0x000000018495c810 libobjc.A.dylib`_objc_terminate() + 124
    frame #6: 0x000000018494c54c libc++abi.dylib`std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 16
    frame #7: 0x000000018494c158 libc++abi.dylib`__cxa_rethrow + 144
    frame #8: 0x000000018495c6e8 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_exception_rethrow + 44
    frame #9: 0x000000018530e344 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 544
    frame #10: 0x000000018719ff84 GraphicsServices`GSEventRunModal + 100

Comment: frame #11: 0x000000018e8ba880 UIKit`UIApplicationMain + 208
  * frame #12: 0x00000001014c1e2c **appname*** `main(argc=1, argv=0x000000016eb5f878) at main.m:14
    frame #13: 0x0000000184e3256c libdyld.dylib`start + 4

Comment: The VC doesn't have a superclass

Comment: No problem on IOS10

Comment: I edited my question with viewdidload code

Comment: `NSKernAttributeName, @(0.66)` They are reversed! Then the message explains clearly it.

Comment: THANK YOU! IOS11 reveals this problems with attributes, there were no crash before...

Comment: @LaurineBaillet can you tell me that what you have changed and its works ?

Comment: In the [NSDictionnary dictionnaryWithObjectsAndKeys : ] the attribute and key were inversed... 
that was : NSKernAttributeName, @(0.66) instead of @(0.66), NSKernAttributeName

Answer (score 1):

That is the culprit line:

```
[self.buttonCancel setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [EATColor colorBlack],  NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[EATFont ElleNovaCExtraBold:12],NSFontAttributeName,NSKernAttributeName, @(0.66), nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

What is happening?

```
[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

That means that at some point there is a `NSNumber` object calling a method `isEqualToString:`. It doesn't knows it (it is a `NSString` method), and then it crashes.

What isn't said is that you don't have to call yourself `isEqualToString:`, it could be an hidden call inside Apple's SDK Code, and that's what is happening.

Attributes Dictionary for `NSAttributedString` must have `NSString` keys, and values must be of the class corresponding in the doc of the key (sometimes it's a `NSNumber`, sometimes a `UIFont`, a `UIColor`), etc.

In your case, you inverted key and object for the last one, `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` waits for Object, then Key.
But in the last filling value you inverted them (`NSKernAttributeName, @(0.66)`). It's still a valid dictionary, but doesn't respects the attributes rules.

So at some points Apple code will check each Key, compare them (calling `isEqualToString:` to know which effects needs to be applied. But it will compare @(0.66) with `NSSomeAttributeName` (`[@(0.66)isEqualToString:NSSomeAttributeName]`) without checking the class of `@(0.66)` first.

The fix:

```
[self.buttonCancel setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [EATColor colorBlack],  NSForegroundColorAttributeName,[EATFont ElleNovaCExtraBold:12],NSFontAttributeName,@(0.66), NSKernAttributeName,  nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

It's simpler to write (and easier to see in one look what is key and what is value):

```
[self.buttonCancel setTitleTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [EATColor colorBlack],
                                            NSFontAttributeName: [EATFont ElleNovaCExtraBold:12], 
                                            NSKernAttributeName: @(0.66)}
                                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```